# What will be faster for GROUP BY statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, indexing, group-by

Imagine that I have the next two SQL Server tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
    id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE UserLogins (
   id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
   user_id INT REFERENCES Users(id) NOT NULL,
   login VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
)
```

And I need to get a count of user logins for each user. And the query result should contain user name, for example.
Which query will work faster:

```
SELECT MAX(name), count(*)
FROM Users u
    INNER JOIN UserLogins ul ON ul.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY u.id
```

or the next one:

```
SELECT name, count(*)
FROM Users u
    INNER JOIN UserLogins ul ON ul.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY u.name
```

So, I'm not sure, if it will be better to group by the column with an index and then use `MAX` or `MIN` aggregate function. Or just group by `Users.name`, which doesn't have any indexes.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Well when you inspect the execution plan which performed better? As a general rule of thumb you should write your queries in the most logical manner possible and only attempt to optimise further if you come across performance issues. SQL Server is designed to take a logical query and make it perform well if it can. So in your case the second query is the most logical.

Comment: Name has no unique constraint. Logically the queries are very different. Don't assume.

Comment: You should also try a subquery, it may be faster than a group by.

Comment: Your first query with about 3k rows of sample data uses avg 6ms of CPU and performs 23 logical reads; your second query also performs 23 logical reads and uses avg 15ms CPU.

Comment: Run your horses.

Comment: Unless performance is really bad, the second query communicates your intention better than the first one. Might as well rewrite that using a subquery since you aren't brining in columns from UserLogins table

Comment: @DaleK But what actually defines "logical"? It turns out that neither of these queries actually defines what OP really wants...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The answer is: neither is really correct.**

The second version is completely wrong as `name` is not unique. The first version is correct, although it may not be efficient.

---

Since `name` has a *functional dependency* on `id`, every unique value of `id` also defines a value of `name`. Grouping by `name` is wrong, because `name` is not necessarily unique. Grouping only by `id` means you need to aggregate `name`, which makes no sense if there is a functional dependency. So you actually want to group by *both* columns:

```sql
SELECT
  u.name,
  count(*)
FROM Users u
    INNER JOIN UserLogins ul ON ul.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY
  u.id,
  u.name;
```

Note that `id` does not actually need to be selected.

This query is almost certainly going to be faster than grouping by `name` alone, because the server cannot deduce that `name` is unique and needs to sort and aggregate it.

It may also be faster than grouping by `id`, although that may depend on whether the optimizer is clever enough to deduce the functional dependency (and therefore no aggregation would be necessary). Even if it isn't clever, this probably won't be slow, as `id` is already unique, so a scan of an index over `id` would not require a sort, only aggregation.